# What do the [[...]] defaults represent in this amchart property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

While drawing a piechart using `amchart`, I came across the following defaults for the `balloon` property:

```
[[title]]: [[percents]]% ([[value]])\n[[description]].
```

Could anyone please tell me what this `[[]]` syntax represents in these defaults?

Answer (score 1):

The short code `[[]]` is used to reference properties in your dataProvider or chart into your format strings. Some `[[shortcodes]]` have special meanings, for example:

- `[[title]]` maps to the value stored in your dataProvider specified by the pie chart's `titleField` for that particular slice (or, if used in a serial chart, the title of the graph),
- `[[percents]]` maps to your the calculated percentage of your value in relation to the sum of all the other values in your dataProvider array. For example, if the sum of all your values in your dataProvider is 200 and a particular slice's valueField is set to 25, `[[percents]]` will give 12.5 for that slice. If you have any precision or number formatting set in your chart configuration, the chart will apply that formatting.
- `[[value]]` maps to the value stored in your dataProvider specified by your pie chart (or graph for serial charts) valueField for that particular slice/column/point. If you have any precision or number formatting set in your chart configuration, the chart will apply that formatting.
- `[[description]]` maps to the value stored in your dataProvider specified by your pie chart's `descriptionField` for that particular slice

The documentation highlights the special `[[shortcodes]]` depending on the context and chart type.

If you have custom fields in your dataProvider that aren't referenced by any fields such as `titleField`, `valueField`, etc, you can reference them directly using the `[[shortcode]]` syntax and the chart will get that property in that dataProvider's array element. For example, given a chart with the `valueField` set to "sliceValue" and `titleField` set to "sliceTitle" and the following dataProvider array:

```
[
  {
    "sliceValue": 5,
    "sliceTitle": "This is a title",
    "extraData": "This is another field that is not mapped by a titleField or valueField"
  },
  // ...
]
```

You can reference the `extraData` field directly by adding `[[extraData]]` to your string. You can also reference `[[sliceValue]]` and `[[sliceTitle]]` directly if you don't want to use `[[value]]` and `[[title]]`, however the chart will not apply any precision or number formatting set in your configuration if you reference `[[sliceValue]]` directly.